# Want to add variable to Format () String output

Tags: vba, date, ms-access

Im sure what im missing is simple but I cant put my finger on it, Im basically doing a school report database and want to show academic years in dropdown list eg "2012 - 2013", I want to show 10 years back and 2 years forward

Here is my code

```
Private Sub Combo2_GotFocus()

   For years = -10 To 2
      Me.Combo2.AddItem Format(DateAdd("yyyy", years, Now), "yyyy" & " - " & "yy")
   Next years

End Sub
```

Output is

2004 - 04
2005 - 05
.
.
.
2016 - 16    ( what I want is 2016 - 17 )

I tried concatinating an incremented date variable instead of " & "yy" to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Private Sub Combo2_GotFocus()

   For years = -10 To 2
      Me.Combo2.AddItem Format(DateAdd("yyyy", years, Now), "yyyy") & "-" & Format(DateAdd("yyyy", years + 1, Now), "yy")
   Next years

End Sub
```

you can use this one as well:

```
Dim y As Integer

For years = -10 To 2
    y = Year(Now) + years
    Me.Combo2.AddItem y & "-" & Right(CStr(y + 1), 2)
Next years
```

Comment: THANKS!! Ive wasted too much time on this small detail. First suggestion didnt work with negative value of years, probably because of its double use, however second suggestion works PERFECTLY. Its new to me, didnt know you could add Year(Now) to an integer variable, will research Right method. Thanks again

Comment: Hm..first one works fine for me..btw glad to help you:)